# Deployment Zend-framework2 on RHEL6.5

Tags: deployment, zend-framework2, rhel6

I've developed a web Zend-framework2 application on windows everything worked fine.

I want to deploy my project to my server on RHEL 6.5. I've tried everything but I can't do so.

This is my project structure

```
|--zend
    |--config
    |--data
    |--module
        |--Application
        |--...
    |--public
        |--index.php
        |--.htaccess
    |--vendor
    |--init_autoloader.php
```

This is the content of .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

This is the content of index.php

```
chdir(dirname(__DIR__));
// Decline static file requests back to the PHP built-in webserver
if (php_sapi_name() === 'cli-server') {
$path = realpath(__DIR__ . parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH));
if (__FILE__ !== $path && is_file($path)) {
    return false;
}
unset($path);
}
// Setup autoloading
require 'init_autoloader.php';
// Run the application!
Zend\Mvc\Application::init(require 'config/application.config.php')->run();
```

my php version is 5.3,rewrite_mod is on
  i've add virtualhost to the httpd.conf like so

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName zend.local
DocumentRoot /var/www/zend/public
<Directory "/var/www/zend/public">
    AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>
```

what should id do ?

Comment: What exactly the problem is?

Comment: i can't access the solution from localhost, 
when i execute php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 on the public directory i can access my app but i can't access it from localhost

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't access it from localhost"? The vhost you included in your question has the server name zend.local so you should be accessing it via. `http://zend.local/`. If that doesn't work, please describe exactly what you are doing and what error you are getting.

Comment: when i open the zend.local on a browser i get this error :
`Notice: Undefined index: APPLICATION_ENV in /var/www/zend/public/index.php on line 5 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /var/www/zend/vendor/zendframework/zend-loader/src/AutoloaderFactory.php on line 25`

Comment: after searching on internet i found that because i installed zend in a different OS and different PHP version this problem occur, i should run composer update the new system to make it work, but i cannot since the server is not connected to the internet , can i manualy update zend framework to make it work ?

Comment: Updating Zend Framework won't help, it sounds like you need to update PHP on your server to a more recent version.

Comment: yes that was the problem i needed to update the php version